# ¿Como enviar variables de un PHP a otro y recuperarlas para usarlas?

Tags: php, formularios, fpdf

tengo un formulario en el cual imprimo variables mediante una consulta a mi base de datos, quiero enviar estas variables a otro archivo php para poder usarlas, lo estoy haciendo actualmente con un formulario y las envió con el método POST y un botón submit, pero al querer recibirlas me manda error y dice que están indefinidas. 
Para explicarme mejor en este formulario imprimo mis variables que guardan una consulta en mi base de datos, primero hago las conexiones, después declaro mis variables y al último las imprimo.

```
    <?php
     $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","id6681618_pagina26","aldair1234")
     or die ("Problemas en la conexion");
     mysql_select_db("id6681618_pagina26",$conexion)
     or die("Problemas en la conexion de la base de datos");
     $inscripciones=mysql_query("SELECT CURP
     FROM inscripciones where
     CURP='$_REQUEST[CURP]'",$conexion) or
     die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());

     if($reg1=mysql_fetch_array($inscripciones))
     {
      /*$folio=$reg1['FOLIO'];
         $nom=$reg1['NOMBRE'];
         $apellipa=$reg1['APELLIDOPA'];
         $apellima=$reg1['APELLIDOMA'];
         $nac=$reg1['FECHA_NACIMIENTO'];
         $curp=$reg1['CURP'];
         $ecivil=$reg1['ECIVIL'];
         $estadonac=$reg1['CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC'];
         $muninac=$reg1['CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC'];
         $estadovive=$reg1['CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE'];
         $munivive=$reg1['CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE'];
         $localidad=$reg1['CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE'];
         $colonia=$reg1['COLONIA_VIVE'];
         $calle=$reg1['CALLE_VIVE'];
         $cp=$reg1['CP_VIVE'];
         $telcasa=$reg1['TEL_CASA'];
         $celular=$reg1['CELULAR'];
         $correo=$reg1['CORREO'];
         $primera=$reg1['PRIMERA_OPCION'];
         $segunda=$reg1['SEGUNDA_OPCION'];
         $tercera=$reg1['TERCERA_OPCION'];
         $sangre=$reg1['TIPO_SANGUINEO'];
         $nacionalidad=$reg1['NACIONALIDAD'];
         $secu=$reg1['NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA'];
         $cct=$reg1['CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA'];
         $nombre_tutor_padre=$reg1['NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR'];
         $ocupacion_tutor_padre=$reg1['OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR'];
         $numero1=$reg1['NUMERO_1'];
         $numero2=$reg1['NUMERO_2'];*/
       $mensaje = "Este CURP ya fue ingresado, por favor intenta nuevamente.";
     echo "<script>";
     echo "alert('$mensaje');";
     echo "history.back();";
     echo "</script>";

     //redirect('formulario.html', 'refresh');
     //header( "refresh:5;url=formulario.html" );

     }  

    else
     {

     mysql_query("insert into 
     inscripciones(NOMBRE, APELLIDOPA, APELLIDOMA, FECHA_NACIMIENTO, CURP,ECIVIL, CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC, CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC, CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE, CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE, CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE, COLONIA_VIVE, 
    CALLE_VIVE, CP_VIVE, TEL_CASA, CELULAR, CORREO,PRIMERA_OPCION, SEGUNDA_OPCION, TERCERA_OPCION, TIPO_SANGUINEO, 
    NACIONALIDAD, NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA, CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA, NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR, OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR, NUMERO_1, NUMERO_2)values
    ('$_REQUEST[NOMBRE]','$_REQUEST[APELLIDOPA]','$_REQUEST[APELLIDOMA]','$_REQUEST[FECHA_NACIMIENTO]','$_REQUEST[CURP]','$_REQUEST[ECIVIL]','$_REQUEST[CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC]',
    '$_REQUEST[CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC]','$_REQUEST[CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE]','$_REQUEST[CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE]','$_REQUEST[CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE]','$_REQUEST[COLONIA_VIVE]',
    '$_REQUEST[CALLE_VIVE]',$_REQUEST[CP_VIVE],$_REQUEST[TEL_CASA],$_REQUEST[CELULAR],'$_REQUEST[CORREO]','$_REQUEST[PRIMERA_OPCION]','$_REQUEST[SEGUNDA_OPCION]','$_REQUEST[TERCERA_OPCION]',
    '$_REQUEST[TIPO_SANGUINEO]',
    '$_REQUEST[NACIONALIDAD]','$_REQUEST[NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA]',
    '$_REQUEST[CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA]',
    '$_REQUEST[NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR]',
    '$_REQUEST[OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR]',$_REQUEST[NUMERO_1],$_REQUEST[NUMERO_2])",


     $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select".mysql_error());

     $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT FOLIO
     FROM inscripciones where
     CURP='$_REQUEST[CURP]'",$conexion) or
     die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
     if($con=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
         $folio=$con['FOLIO'];
     }
     mysql_close($conexion);

     print '<script language="JavaScript">'; 
     print 'alert("Proceso terminado");'; 

     print '</script>'; 

$nom=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE'];
$apellipa=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOPA'];
$apellima=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOMA'];
$nac=$_REQUEST['FECHA_NACIMIENTO'];
$curp=$_REQUEST['CURP'];
$ecivil=$_REQUEST['ECIVIL'];
$estadonac=$_REQUEST['CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC'];
$muninac=$_REQUEST['CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC'];
$estadovive=$_REQUEST['CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE'];
$munivive=$_REQUEST['CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE'];
$localidad=$_REQUEST['CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE'];
$colonia=$_REQUEST['COLONIA_VIVE'];
$calle=$_REQUEST['CALLE_VIVE'];
$cp=$_REQUEST['CP_VIVE'];
$telcasa=$_REQUEST['TEL_CASA'];
$celular=$_REQUEST['CELULAR'];
$correo=$_REQUEST['CORREO'];
$primera=$_REQUEST['PRIMERA_OPCION'];
$segunda=$_REQUEST['SEGUNDA_OPCION'];
$tercera=$_REQUEST['TERCERA_OPCION'];
$sangre=$_REQUEST['TIPO_SANGUINEO'];
$nacionalidad=$_REQUEST['NACIONALIDAD'];
$secu=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA'];
$cct=$_REQUEST['CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA'];
$nombre_tutor_padre=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR'];
$ocupacion_tutor_padre=$_REQUEST['OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR'];
$numero1=$_REQUEST['NUMERO_1'];
$numero2=$_REQUEST['NUMERO_2'];



}

      ?>
```

Acá las imprimo:

```
    <h1>Verifica que los datos que ingresaste sean correctos, si así lo es, presiona para generar tu ficha.</h1>


     <form action="Prueba3/reporte.php" method="post" name="Hola">
   <div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      FOLIO 
    <input name="FOLIO" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $folio; ?>" />    
    </label>
  </div>

   <div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      NOMBRE
      <input name="NOMBRE" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nom; ?>" />    
      </label>
  </div>


<div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO PATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOPA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellipa ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO MATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellima?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
      <input name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      CURP
      <input name="CURP" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $curp ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      ESTADO CIVIL 
      <input name="ECIVIL" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $ecivil ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      ESTADO DE NACIMIENTO 
      <input name="CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $estadonac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      MUNICIPIO DE NACIMIENTO
      <input name="CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $muninac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      ESTADO DONDE VIVE ACTUALMENTE 
      <input name="CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $estadovive ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      MUNICIPIO DONDE VIVE ACTUALMENTE 
      <input name="CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $munivive ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     LOCALIDAD
      <input name="CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $localidad ?>" />  
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      COLONIA 
      <input  name="COLONIA_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $colonia ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
   <label>
      CALLE 
      <input name="CALLE_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $calle ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       CÓDIGO POSTAL 
       <input name="CP_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $cp ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      TELÉFONO DE CASA
      <input name="TEL_CASA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $telcasa ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
     CELULAR
     <input name="CELULAR" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $celular ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
      <input name="CORREO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $correo ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      PRIMERA OPCIÓN
     <input name="PRIMERA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $primera ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     SEGUNDA OPCIÓN
     <input name="SEGUNDA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $segunda ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      TERCERA OPCIÓN 
     <input name="TERCERA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $tercera ?>" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       TIPO SANGUÍNEO
   <input name="TIPO_SANGUINEO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $sangre ?>" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      NACIONALIDAD
   <input name="NACIONALIDAD" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nacionalidad ?>" />       
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       NOMBRE DE SECUNDARIA DE PROCEDENCIA
       <input name="NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $secu ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      CCT DE LA SECUNDARIA DE PROCEDENCIA
      <input name="CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $cct ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      NOMBRE DEL PADRE O TUTOR
      <input  name="NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nombre_tutor_padre ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     OCUPACIÓN DEL PADRE O TUTOR
     <input type="text" name="OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $ocupacion_tutor_padre ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
       NÚMERO DE CONTACTO 1
       <input name="NUMERO_1" type="number" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $numero1 ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-3">
    <label>
       NÚMERO DE CONTACTO 2
       <input name="NUMERO_2" type="number" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $numero2 ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-3">

  </div>
   <div class="col-3">

  </div>



    <div class="col-3">

  </div>


   <div class="col-3">

  </div>



    <div class="col-3">

  </div>


  <div class="col-submit">
    <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="enviar1" value="Generar" >
        <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
            </section>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="col-submit">
    <input type="button" class="submitbtn" name="enviar" value="No" onclick = "this.form.action = 'eliminar.php'; this.form.submit()">
    <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
    </section>!-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

elems.forEach(function(html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html);
);
</script>

  </form>
```

Y al final las recibo en mi otro archivo PHP:

```
    <?php
   //include('plantilla.php');
   require('conexion.php');
   require 'fpdf.php';
   class PDF extends FPDF
  {
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('umss.png',20,13,55);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
        $this->SetX(100);
        $this->MultiCell(94,4,'Secretaría de Educación Pública',0,'R',0);
        $this->SetX(100);
        $this->MultiCell(94,4,'Subsecretaría de Educación Media Superior ', 0,'R',0);
        $this->SetX(74);
        $this->MultiCell(120,4,'Unidad de Educación Media Superior Tecnológica Industrial y de Servicios',0,'R',0);
        $this->SetX(164);
        $this->MultiCell(30,4,'Estado de Hidalgo CETIS No. 26', 0,'R',0);
        // Movernos a la derecha
        $this->Ln(5);
    }
   /*$idr= $_POST['CURP'];
   $strConsulta = "SELECT * FROM inscripciones where CURP = '$idr'";
   $alumno = mysql_query($strConsulta);
   $fila = mysql_fetch_array($alumno);*/
   //$abr=$_POST["FOLIO"];

   function Footer()
    {
        // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Número de página
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
  }

   $abr=($_POST['FOLIO']);
    $fl=$abr;
    $nom=$_POST['NOMBRE'];
    $pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A4');

   $pdf->AddPage();

   $pdf->Ln(5);
   $pdf->SetX(50);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'BU', 12);
   $pdf->Cell(100, 10,'PASE DE INGRESO AL EXAMEN', 0,0,'C');

   // Título
   $pdf->SetX(170);
   $pdf->Cell(23,27,'Foto',1,0,'C');

   // Salto de línea
   $pdf->Ln(20);

   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
   $pdf->SetX(10);
   $pdf->MultiCell(100,10,utf8_decode('NÚMERO DE FOLIO: '.$fl),0,'C',0);
   $pdf->SetX(20);
   $pdf->MultiCell(100,10,utf8_decode('Nombre: '.$nom),0,'C',0);
   $pdf->Output();
?>
```

El problema es que no está recibiendo lo que guarda el input, así que quisiera saber como recuperar el valor de mis variables que definí en el otro archivo PHP, espero puedan ayudarme, graciaaaaas. :)

Comment: Usa `mysqli_ ` en vez de `mysql_`, está deprecado

Comment: Oscar bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En este caso Ajax será tu mejor aliado. Te invito a descubrir como funciona (aquí mismo hay buenas preguntas/respuestas sobre el tema). Cuando lo descubras no podrás soltarlo, sólo que al principio parece complicado, pero no lo es.

Comment: Oscar, creo que el problema esta en los input de tu form, reemplaza disabled="false"  por  readonly="readonly"

Comment: @PatrickArguello si me funciono, muchísimas graciaaaas, me has salvado. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reemplaza  *disabled="false"*   por   *readonly="readonly"*

Los elementos que tienen el atributo **readonly** no se pueden modificar, pero su contenido se envía cuando el usuario envía el formulario.

Los elementos con el atributo **disabled**   ***no sólo no se pueden modificar sino que no se envían junto con el resto de campos del formulario***.

Otra de sus principales diferencias es que los elementos readonly pueden obtener el foco del navegador (al pulsar Tabulador varias veces, podrías llegar a seleccionarlo) mientras que los elementos disabled no pueden obtener el foco.

[Fuente](https://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/231/cuales-son-las-diferencias-entre-los-atributos-disabled-y-readonly-de-los-campos-de-texto-de-los-formularios/)

Comment: @Oscar Reyes esta es la explicación.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar recibiéndolas con **$_REQUEST**:

```
...
$abr=$_REQUEST['FOLIO']; // Aunque, sin los parentesis supongo
    $fl=$abr;
    $nom=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE'];
    $pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A4');
...
```